Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'. Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'
i want to run my flutter project but got this error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
 > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform appcompat-resources-1.7.0.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-    resources:1.7.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=23, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
  > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\a497fff099218d09578e12c23e9f46a7\transformed\jetified-appcompat-resources-1.7.0-runtime.jar.
     > Error while dexing.


Failed to transform appcompat-1.7.0.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=23, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\User.gradle\caches\transforms-3\039b4c1f544ca04a871af3153003f63c\transformed\appcompat-1.7.0-runtime.jar.
> Error while dexing.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

this is my android/app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" // Add this line
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader ->
    localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionCode")
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = "1"
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionName")
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = "1.0"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.my_tflite_app"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion '21.1.6528147'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID   (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
       applicationId = "com.example.my_tflite_app"
       // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
       // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdk = 23 // Updated minSdkVersion to 23
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

// Add these lines for Firebase
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.0') 
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth' // Add Firebase Auth dependency
}


I have solved it，downgrade the verison of androidx.appcompact to 1.6.1 as 1.7.0

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thank you sir, spent a few hours on this...

Try this:
Change compileSdkVersion in android/app/build.gradle:
android {
    namespace "App Name"
    compileSdk 34 //Change here
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
}

And also change minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion:
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24 
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
    }

Also you can add multidex manually if this isn't work:
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1' //enter the latest multidex version
}
android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}


thank you for your help but i still facing the same issue

In a Flutter project, we don't need to add the following dependencies:
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.0') 
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'

These dependencies from the build.gradle should be removed if you are not natively creating views in Android. Even to integrate the firebase in a flutter project we don't need to add the dependencies for Android/iOS separately. Read here to learn how to integrate firebase in flutter apps.
